# Did the previous owners tile over the edges of the fireplace insert?

Tags: fireplace, renovation

The previous owners of my house "renovated" the existing wood burning fireplace.  They failed to add a hearth so I cannot use for wood.  Wanted to replace with an electric insert but they may have also tiled over the edges of the existing wood burning insert, but I'm not sure and I don't have any experience with fireplace inserts.

From the supplied photos, does it look like they tiled over the edges of the existing insert?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would say NO ..

Comment: The only way I can see to determine whether or not there is tile overlapping the front face of the fireplace is to remove a small portion of the grout on the left or right side and see if there's more metal past the edge of the tile. I've had 6 prefab fireplaces, and on all 6 the non-combustable material (tile, brick,, or stone) has overlapped the front face of the fireplace. One suggestion would be to cut out a segment of the flooring to insert a non-combustable hearth of the correct size so you can use this fireplace as designed. Less work and less money.

Comment: I would agree that cutting out the floor in front for a hearth would be the easy solution here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a simple internet search yielded the owner/installation manual for the product, and said manual includes all the OP needs to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Fireplaces do not simply set in place. They are always in some fashion fastened to the framing on either side of the fireplace, so it will not move for any reason, especially a wood burning fireplace that can move when heavy chunks of wood are tossed into it. The fasteners are covered by the fireplace surround.

You may be able to find an insert that will do what you need, rather than breaking tile to change out the whole unit.

Answer (score 1):

A quick DuckDuckGo search for "Marco Factory Built Fireplace DF-36E" yielded [this site](https://www.allpartsinc.com/36-wood-burning-fireplace-36e.html) which includes this image:

[image]

The image shows a flange on the left and top side (and, presumably, a flange on the right side that we can't see in this isometric drawing angle). The flanges don't appear to be in your picture, so it's safe to assume they're used for attaching the insert to the wall, then hidden behind the tile.

That site also has a user/installation manual with all the dimensions. You can compare your visible dimensions to those sowing in the instructions to confirm that there are hidden flanges.